# Why this js script does not work in asp.net after postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this code:

```
 if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", "alert('test');jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.newslettersubscribe').position().top }, 'slow');",true);
    }
```

I don't understand why the scrolling to the div which is on the bottom of the page, does not work.

Please note that `alert('test')` is appearing...

For sure I have a div with class `newslettersubscribe` on my page.

**UPDATE**:
- my js files are loaded using Script Manager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" >
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/cufon-yui.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/helvetica_neue.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/jquery.cycle.all.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/default.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/js/swfobject-2.1.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

so I need to find a way to run this inline script AFTER these external js files were loaded...

**UPDATE 2:** After a chat discussion with dknaack we noticed that there was also an issue with `position`. I've replaced with `offset` at his recommandation and now it's working!!!

Thanks a lot **dknaack** !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your code.

The problem is that you don't wait till the `DOM` is fully loaded.

Change your `RegisterClientScriptBlock` to this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", "alert('test');jQuery(function(){jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.newslettersubscribe').position().top }, 'slow');});", true);
```

Check out this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/zYh7k/)

### Update

Make sure your `jQuery<version>.js` file is above your script. Have a look at the Html Sourcecode of your loaded page. You should add the jQuery file to the `<head>` section of your sitemaster.

Comment: Seems indeed right what you said, I replaced my code with your, still the scrolling does not work in my case... This div is inside a user control and I put this code in Page_Load of the user control, but still it does not work...

Comment: I looked into the source code of the page and noticed that this js is put BEFORE the jquery js file is loaded...maybe this is the cause..

Comment: Do you have added the `jQuery<version>.js` to your sitemaster ? Have a look at the html of your loaded page. The jQuery file must be over your script.

Comment: ;) Thats it. Add your jQuery file in the `<head>` section of your sitemaster.

Comment: Sorry for coming back: I use a Script Manager to load my jquery stuff and other js files...I really need this Script Manager..is there a way to update the answer based on script manager? I've tried: `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "key", "alert('test');jQuery(function(){jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.newslettersubscribe').position().top }, 'slow');});", true);` but still it does not work...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6921/discussion-between-dknaack-and-cristian-boariu)

Answer (score 2):

```
string jsScript1 = @"
jQuery(function () {
   alert('test');
   jQuery('html, body')
     .animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.newslettersubscribe').position().top }, 'slow');
});"

if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Javascript", jsScript1,true);
    }
```

Trick to have nice looking js in C# code, also you need to run this animate after the DOM is done loading -- do this by passing a function to jQuery()

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues. The first is that you probably want to use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` instead of `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock`. This will place your script at the bottom of the page instead of the top. Script blocks are more for functions that you want to place on the page that you may call later.

The second, as mentioned by the other answers, is that you should wrap your animation code inside of some client lifecycle event. You can hook into jQuery's `ready` event like this:

```
jQuery(function() { /* Your Code */ });
```

Which will execute your code when the DOM is ready to be manipulated, but before the page actually finished loading. If you want wait until the page is done loading, you can do:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() { /* Your Code */ });
```